# Copy all files in a folder which have the same name as files in a separate folder

Tags: shell, windows-explorer, file-management

Let me explain:

I am going through a huge icon set, and choosing the icons I like. I have chosen maybe 250 out of 3000 icons. The way the icons are split up are like this:

```
Icons
  -> 16x16
   -> a.png
   -> b.png
   -> c.png
  -> 32x32
   -> a.png
   -> b.png
   -> c.png
```

I've copied the icons I want from the `32x32` folder, in to a folder `"Big Icons"`. I want now to take the name of every icon I've selected in `"Big Icons"` and use that to select the icons with the same name in the `16x16` folder, to then copy those icons in to a folder called `"Small Icons"`

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have any scripting/programming environments set up (e.g. PowerShell, Python, or even C#)?  This would be trivial to do in a PowerShell or Python script, or even to create a C# application to do it.

Comment: *looks at Visual Studio* Don't know why I didn't think of that... I'll whip up a quick C# Console app to do it!

Comment: I'm on my Linux machine right now, so no VS/C# for me.  If you're comfortable with C#, there's a lot of built-in system I/O classes which can handle file management for you.  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254339/how-to-loop-through-all-the-files-in-a-directory-in-c-net) should get you started ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the BigIcons folder in a cmd window:

```
for %%X in (*) do copy .\16x16\%%X .\SmallIcons\
```

assumes all folders are in same parent directory.